# How do I detect what a facebook access token belongs to?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In our web application a user grants us access to their Facebook account, which gives us their long term access token.  The user then makes a choice if the integration should be for their user timeline or for a specific Facebook page that they administrate.  If they pick a page then we swap out their user access token with their page access token and go on our merry way.   That has been successfully live for a while.

Now I want to add some code so if you are authenticated against a page we can query for the engagements field (/me?fields=engagement) (essentially the details about like counts for the page).  However, this query obviously fails if you navigate to this resource with a user access token, because there is no "engagement" field on User.

Is there some way I can query the "/me" api resource and know if it's a user or a page without parsing the error message?

Comment: why not just store the info in your database, if it is a page token or user token?

Comment: Because the integration was already live and there's no easy way to retroactively do this, and there's not much use for the flag outside of this one scenario going forward.

Comment: sure, you can do that one time with a script, to check out the existing ones.